# How to hide a HTML table with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code needs to show/hide the entire table based on another field input, but for some reason it's not working.
This sort of a code works fine with regular div elements. What is different with tables?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#DD').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
      $('#hiddenTable').show();
    } else {
      $('#hiddenTable').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DD" id="DDid" class="DDclass">
  <div style="padding-bottom:2%; font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 100%;">
    Have you contacted or been contacted by our customer service team?<br>
    <select name="DD2" id="DDid2" class="DDclass2">
      <option value="No" >No</option>
      <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<table class="hiddenTable" id="hiddenTable" style="display:none;">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Strongly Agree</th>
    <th>Somewhat Agree</th>
    <th>Neither Agree nor Disagree</th>
    <th>Somewhat Disagree</th>
    <th>Strongly Disagree</th>
    <th>Not Applicable</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>I received answer(s) quickly</td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="QuickAnswers" value="Strongly Agree" data-col="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="QuickAnswers" value="Somewhat Agree" data-col="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="QuickAnswers" value="Neither Agree nor Disagree" data-col="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="QuickAnswers" value="Somewhat Disagree" data-col="4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="QuickAnswers" value="Strongly Disagree" data-col="5"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="QuickAnswers" value="Not Applicable" data-col="6"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Place your javascript at the bottom of your page. or try the $(selector).on('click', function(){ //code here });

Comment: Change `#DD` to `#DDid2`

Comment: All `jQuery#hide` does is add `display:none` to the element, with some fancy caching. "Equivelant to calling`jQuery#css.." http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: You cannot have two IDs to an element `id="DD" id="DDid"` This is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

You need to change id `$('#DD').change(function(){` to `$('#DDid2').change(function(){`

```js
$(function() {
    $('#DDid2').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "Yes") 
        {
            $('#hiddenTable').show();
        } else {
            $('#hiddenTable').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DD" id="DDid" class="DDclass">
      <div style="padding-bottom:2%; font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 100%;">
      Have you contacted or been contacted by our customer service team?
        <br>
      <select name="DD2" id="DDid2" class="DDclass2">
       <option value="No" >No</option>
       <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
     </select>
      </div>
     </div>


 <table class="hiddenTable" id="hiddenTable" style="display:none;">
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Strongly Agree</th>
    <th>Somewhat Agree</th>
    <th>Neither Agree nor Disagree</th>
    <th>Somewhat Disagree</th>
    <th>Strongly Disagree</th>
    <th>Not Applicable</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>I received answer(s) quickly</td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="QuickAnswers" value="Strongly Agree" data-col="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="QuickAnswers" value="Somewhat Agree" data-col="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="QuickAnswers" value="Neither Agree nor Disagree" data-col="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="QuickAnswers" value="Somewhat Disagree" data-col="4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="QuickAnswers" value="Strongly Disagree" data-col="5"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="QuickAnswers" value="Not Applicable" data-col="6"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed this obvious thing. This worked.

Comment: You cannot have two IDs to an element `id="DD" id="DDid"` This is incorrect.